# Error with TimeZone

Tags: java, plsql

- I have calling spq procedure through Java code.
- For mailing purpose I have using SMTP Server.

When I'm invoking reset password I have receiving mail but getting different time zone like I'm in India when I'm hitting reset password at the time is 4PM I have receiving mail but in the inbox it is showing 8PM why it is showing like that still I'm not sure.

Please give some suggestions any one.

Comment: Elaborate more about error. Post your code. Also post what is desired output and what are your getting

Comment: -Problem is when i'm invoking resetpassword I have receiving mail but getting different time zone like I'm invoking reset password at the time is 4PM received at a time but my inbox we have a time right in inbox at that time is different like 6PM